# Show that if $X_1,X_2,$. . . be a sequence of r.v.'s on a countable $Ω$ such that $X_n → X$ in probability implies $X_n → X$ a.s.

Tags: probability

Show that if $X_1,X_2,$. . . be a sequence of r.v.'s on a countable $Ω$ such that $X_n → X$ in probability implies $X_n → X$ a.s.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\omega$ be such that $P(\{\omega\})>0$.

Since $X_n \to X$ in probability, for all $\epsilon > 0$ and all sufficiently large $n$ we have

> $$P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) < P(\{ \omega \}).\tag{1}$$

(1) implies that $\omega \notin \{ \omega' \in \Omega: |X_n(\omega') - X(\omega')| > \epsilon \}$.

Hence, for all $\epsilon>0$ and all sufficiently large $n$, $|X_n(\omega) - X_n(\omega)| \leq \epsilon$. That is,

> $$X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega). \tag{2}$$

Since (2) holds for all $\omega$ with positive probability and $\Omega$ is countable, it follows that (2) holds for all $\omega$ in a set with probability $1$. In other words, $X_n \to X$ a.s.